# How can I create podcast posts automatically from the contents of a particular directory?

Tags: podcasting, automation

All of the Wordpress Podcasting plugins I have seen allow you to easily insert a podcast into a post.  Is there any way to automate the creation of the post (and the podcast feed) by simply uploading the podcast into a specific directory?

For example I could upload 10 podcasts into the `/media/` directory and then it would automatically create a post for each of the 10 files I uploaded.  Ideally it would take the information from the ID3 tags.

The key factor here is not having to do anything in wordpress after the initial setup.

Comment: Sounds like a good plugin idea :)

Answer (score 2):

I've created a [very basic plugin](http://www.fractured-state.com/2011/09/mp3-to-post-plugin/) for that now.

Let me know what you think or if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Not sure when I'm going to have the chance to try it out but I'll let you know when I do.